# Golang POST request to API returns 400, while the same request with e. g. Postman returns 200

Tags: api, post, go, request

In my Go application I use a Web API, which accepts a POST request and returns a token if it is successful.

The URL is the following: "https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/nb/create?SCOPE=xxxx&EMAIL_ID=xxxx&PASSWORD=xxxx"

If I send this in Postman or any other tool, I get the status code 200 with the expected body, but in my go code the same request returns error code 400.

```
url := "https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/nb/create?SCOPE=xxxx&EMAIL_ID=xxxx&PASSWORD=xxxx"

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
log.Println(err)

res, err := client.Do(req)
log.Println(err)

defer res.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
log.Println(err)

fmt.Println(res)
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

All errors are nil, but the res struct contains 400 Bad Request and the last output (of the body) is empty.

### Output:

```
&{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Date:[Sat, 03 Mar 2018 16:48:35 GMT] Connection:[keep-alive] Set-Cookie:[a8c61fa0dc=5f224f2ab9d067cfce10fd0b7fae48bf; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly] Server:[ZGS]] 0xc04225a080 -1 [chunked] false false map[] 0xc042034a00 0xc0421bc370}
```

I would appreciate any help, because I don't know where this problem comes from.

Comment: I have also faced same issue when I am working with micro service. Can you print the output of error you should get on console when running your program using go run in terminal

Comment: I updated my question and added the output, but as i said, the errors are nil and the response "object" contains 400.

Answer (score 1):

Url-encoded parameters should be provided in body parameter not as query string. So this can be a problem too. Set your paramters in body implementing `io.Reader`.

```
func NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)
```

Set the header Content-Type in your request before sending it using `Client.Do`.

```
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Since postman is smart enough to set the headers for you. Thats why no error.
The whole code becomes

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)
func main(){

    url := "https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/nb/create"

    var data url.Values{}
    data.Set("SCOPE","xxxx")
    data.Add("EMAIL","xxxx")
    data.Add("PASSWORD","xxxx")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    log.Println(err)

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    log.Println(err)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    log.Println(err)

    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```

Comment: I already tried setting the Content-Type before, but i did not know that you need to pass the url Values extra. Thank You

Comment: `url.Values{}` is actually a type `map[string][]string` which is a created [Type](https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=22818:22849#L783)

Comment: Do you have an idea why the parameters still aren't sent or received by the API with your approach? The API sends the exact same message it would send when you provide no parameters at all. If any parameter is corrupted it would return a specific error message, so that's not the case

Comment: will you show the error message that you are getting also are you able to get the posted parameters

Comment: This is the result I get from the API (i would expect it to have RESULT set to TRUE and instead of CAUSE return a TOKEN:

`#
#Tue Mar 06 12:20:41 PST 2018
CAUSE=null
RESULT=FALSE`

I don't know what you mean by "get the posted parameters".

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue. The reason for `401` simply means the invalid authorization token. Later I noticed that Postman executes the `Pre-request script` that updates the header every time. You can pull in the same pre-request script code in golang and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Same question here, try to make a POST request with some QUERY params in url, which works fine in Postman but always got Http 400 in go debug with all the same params (Query params , post body ,headers and MD5 sign)

```
timeStr := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
serverUrlAll = serverUrlAll + "?token="+token+"&provider="+provide+"&timestamp="+timeStr+"&signature="+signature
contentBody := strings.NewReader(signString)
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST",serverUrlAll , contentBody)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Finally found the **blank in query url** will cause the error , remove the blank and it works in my case.